# keyboard shortcut to switch focus between separate X screens?

Tags: xorg, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors

I'm using XFCE on a dual monitor setup, with Xorg configured to separate X screens (neither twinview nor cinerama is working on GF470 with latest nvidia drivers). I'm not using xrandr.

Suppose I have firefox running on one screen (:0.0) and thunderbird on the other (:0.1). When I want to switch focus from thunderbird to firefox, I need to move my mouse pointer to the firefox window and click (alt-tab switches between windows on a single screen only).

Is there any keyboard shortcut for switching focus between screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure this out for myself on Ubuntu 10.10 (Gnome in my case). There doesn't appear to be a built-in shortcut, but there is a useful utility called DualscreenMouseUtils:

1. Download dualscreen-mouse-utils archive from [here](http://digamma.cs.unm.edu/trac.dmohr/wiki/DualscreenMouseUtils)
2. Extract the archive: `tar -zxvf`
3. Build the util: `make mouse-switchscreen`
4. Copy the created executable to a bin directory, e.g. /usr/local/bin
5. Set up a keyboard shortcut using your window manager that runs the executable whenever the shortcut is used.

Comment: Someone should package that...

Comment: dualscreen-mouse-utils does not compile on Ubuntu 11.10; to compile it, you need to modify the Makefile by putting this line below `mouse-switchscreen`:
 `$(CC) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)`

Comment: Does that archive still exist?  Currently getting trac errors...  And most importantly: does this also work for more than two screens, or does it just flip between two?

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel, in case you're still interested: see http://askubuntu.com/a/692151/72216